# Can't use AWS Cli command on PHP exec

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu, I'm trying to download file from s3 Bucket to my mounted shared folder from windows using

```
exec('aws s3 cp s3://bname/05-06-2019/01600exp.zip /var/www/mnt', $output, $result);
print_r($output); //Array()
print_r($result); //1
```

it returns null, but when I do it on terminal it works. I saw some of this same question but none of them works.

I already tried to change permission of `/var/www/mnt` folder to

- $USER:$USER
- root:root
- www-data:www-data

and the chmod to 0755, 0777 and still not work.

Comment: I wonder whether `exec()` runs as a different user on the Ubuntu system, and that user doesn't have credentials defined? Are you running this on an Amazon EC2 instance with an associated IAM Role? You could always use the [PHP SDK for AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html) instead of calling out to the AWS CLI.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein My PHP runs on `www-data` but which one should I run?. No, I'm working it on our local Dev server, Yes I have installed PHP SDK on my project

Comment: It work's now I changed my User to www-data then I added the credentials after I run I'm able to run the aws cli